# Best way to find DOM elements with css selectors

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

What's the easiest way to find Dom elements with a css selector, without using a library?

```
function select( selector ) {
 return [ /* some magic here please :) */ ]
};

select('body')[0] // body;

select('.foo' ) // [div,td,div,a]

select('a[rel=ajax]') // [a,a,a,a]
```

This question is purely academical. I'm interested in learning how this is implemented and what the 'snags' are. What would the expected behavior of this function be? ( return array, or return first Dom element, etc ).

Comment: The answer you accepted for this question a decade ago is very out of date. It would be worth changing your selection to one that is more suited for today: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4145389/19068

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These days, doing this kind of stuff without a library is madness. However, I assume you want to learn how this stuff works. I would suggest you look into the source of jQuery or one of the other javascript libraries.

With that in mind, the selector function has to include a lot of if/else/else if or switch case statements in order to handle all the different selectors. Example:

```
function select( selector ) {
 if(selector.indexOf('.') > 0) //this might be a css class
   return document.getElementsByClassName(selector);
 else if(selector.indexOf('#') > 0) // this might be an id
   return document.getElementById(selector);
 else //this might be a tag name
   return document.getElementsByTagName(selector);
 //this is not taking all the different cases into account, but you get the idea.
};
```

Comment: Not necessarily - look at Sizzle (jQuery's engine) and you won't see any of this.

Comment: This is unnecessary in modern browsers. querySelectedAll() is a better solution.

Answer (score 73):

In addition to the custom hacks, in recent browsers you can use the native methods defined in the [W3C Selectors API Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/), namely [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll("#score > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(2)");
```

Comment: Docs and browser supports https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: This should now be the selected answer - all modern browsers are supported except IE7? In August 2013, that's good enough for me!

Comment: When using querySelectorAll you will get an array of elements so if you are expecting one element you whould add [0] at the end. Or you can simply use document.querySelector()

Answer (score 3):

Creating a selector engine is no easy task. I would suggest learning from what already exists:

- [**Sizzle**](http://sizzlejs.com/) (Created by Resig, used in jQuery)
- [**Peppy**](http://jamesdonaghue.com/static/peppy/) (Created by James Donaghue)
- [**Sly**](http://digitarald.de/journal/89737433/rolling-out-sly-the-javascript-selector-engine/) (Created by Harald Kirschner)

Comment: Great links! Really interesting. Specially that performance test runner.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice snippet i've used some times. Its really small and neat. It has support for the all common css selectors.

http://www.openjs.com/scripts/dom/css_selector/

Answer (score 0):

No there's no built in way. Essentially, if you decide to go without jQuery, you'll be replicating a buggy version of it in your code.

Comment: To be fair, JQuery isn't the only library that provides selector-style functionality, just the most prominent.

Comment: Yes, of course. By "without jQuery", I mean without an external library of choice.