# Find a child element in html5 javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I know html5 supported javascript [can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886863/best-way-to-find-dom-elements-with-css-selectors) to select elements: document.getElementById(selector)
I know jquery can be used to find a child element of another element with selectors.

But pure javascript has gotten better (for browsers that support HTML5) and I would like to do without jQuery. So it has document.getElementById to find elements.

Edit: So it's different because I want to avoid searching the entire page without jQuery.

Comment: Post some html structure. querySelectorAll or querySelector will do trick for u

Comment: @ShoaibChikate — Why? It's a general question with a clear description of the general markup structure being dealt with.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. The other question selects element anywhere on the page, I want to give the selector a startpoint.